# how can we get general link field from rendering parameter in sitecore sxa using scriban

Tags: sxa, scriban

I am trying to access general link field from rendering parameter in sitecore sxa using scriban
but it is accessing whole link tag with page id instead of url.
how can get normal url?
[image]

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ sc_parameter 'Specialist1' }}">test</a>
```

I am using above given code to render the field from rendering parameter

Answer (score 1):

When you use `sc_parameter` that way, you get the raw value of the field, instead of link information.

You can use `sc_field` and pass your css classes as parameters like:

```
{{ sc_field i_item 'Specialist1' [['class', 'btn btn-primary']] }}
```

Scriban documentation can be found here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-embedded-functions-for-the-scriban-template.html

Comment: thanks Marek issue got resolved

Comment: If my answered helped you, mark it as a correct one so it can help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

sc_parameter just gives you the raw values for Internal and External link and that is the reason you are getting the  html as the result.

So if you need to get the URL you might need to consider creating custom scriban functions as described in https://blogs.perficient.com/2020/08/03/sxa-scriban-creating-custom-embedded-function-in-scriban/ and using the General Link related logics in your custom scriban function.